# MPU 6050 Accelorometer Gyroscope code is giving me an angle of 75 degrees when it's suppose to be 90 degrees

Tags: python, mpu6050

I used a bubble level and Angle apps to verify that my MPU 6050 is actually rotated 90 degrees. Even so, my code tells me that the MPU 6050 is rotated ~75 degrees when it is in fact rotated around 90 degrees. Can someone please help me solve this problem? I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 B with Raspbian Stretch.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smbus
import math

# Power management registers
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c

def read_byte(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)

def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))

def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)

def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # or bus = smbus.SMBus(1) for Revision 2 boards
address = 0x68       # This is the address value read via the i2cdetect command

# Now wake the 6050 up as it starts in sleep mode
bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)

while True:
    #print("gyro data")
    #print("---------")

    gyro_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
    gyro_yout = read_word_2c(0x45)
    gyro_zout = read_word_2c(0x47)

    #print("gyro_xout: ", gyro_xout, " scaled: ", (gyro_xout / 131))
    #print("gyro_yout: ", gyro_yout, " scaled: ", (gyro_yout / 131))
    #print("gyro_zout: ", gyro_zout, " scaled: ", (gyro_zout / 131))

    #print
    #print("accelerometer data")
    #print("------------------")

    accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
    accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
    accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)

    accel_xout_scaled = accel_xout / 16384.0
    accel_yout_scaled = accel_yout / 16384.0
    accel_zout_scaled = accel_zout / 16384.0

    #print("accel_xout: ", accel_xout, " scaled: ", accel_xout_scaled)
    #print("accel_yout: ", accel_yout, " scaled: ", accel_yout_scaled)
    #print("accel_zout: ", accel_zout, " scaled: ", accel_zout_scaled)

    print("x rotation: " , get_x_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled),"\t\ty rotation: " , get_y_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))
    #print("y rotation: " , get_y_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a noise-filter data-fusion algorithm to convert the raw data from MPU into angle. Go through this [instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Angle-Meter/) . It should help you achieve your goal.